# Call Web API from Web Form application to calculate two input numbers

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to learn to create Web API.
I have a Web Form application with two input box for Number-1 and Number-2 to enter numbers and one DropdownList 
Dropdown List that contains the following:

•   Add
•   Subtract
•   Multiply
•   Divide
Once the user made his/her selection, he/she should be able to click a button that calls the Web services, which performs the action selected in the above dropdown list and then display the result on the page.

The second application is Web API
The web API does the following:
1.  Adds two numbers, for example, 1 and 3 and the result, together with the two numbers, is saved into a SQL database and then returned to the calling Web Forms application.
2.  Subtracts two numbers, for example, 1 and 3 and the result, together with the two numbers, is saved into a SQL database and then returned to the calling Web Forms application.
3.  Divides two numbers, for example, 1 and 3 and the result, together with the two numbers, is saved into a SQL database and then returned to the calling Web Forms application.
4.  The results of the above should be returned by the Web  API to the Web Forms app so that the Web Forms app will display the value

Here is my code for Web Form but how can I call Web API, can any one please guide how can I create this Web API and how can I execute this application.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter No 1."></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNo1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Enter No 2."></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNo2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Add</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Subtract</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Multiply</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">Divide</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" Text="Call Web API" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On your button click, make use of ajax to post to your web api.

Comment: Google is your friend - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/consuming-web-service-in-Asp-Net-web-application/